# iterator cannot be dereferenced

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, iterator

I'm new with C++ and I'm having troubles completing my assignment. The probem is, I have a class like below:

```
template<class VertexLabel, class EdgeLabel> class Graph {
public:
    Graph() : id(0){};

    class Vertex {
    private:
        unsigned long id;
        VertexLabel label;
    public:
        Vertex() : label(VertexLabel()){}
        Vertex(VertexLabel lbl) : label(lbl) {};
        const VertexLabel &getLabel() const;
        const VertexLabel &setLabel(const VertexLabel &other);
        const unsigned long &getId() const;
        void setId(unsigned long id);
        ~Vertex(){}
    };

    class Edge {
    private:
        Vertex from, to;
        EdgeLabel edgeLabel;
    public:
        Edge() : from(Vertex()), to(Vertex()), edgeLabel(EdgeLabel()) {};
        Edge(Vertex start, Vertex end) : from(start), to(end), edgeLabel(EdgeLabel()) {};
        Edge(Vertex start, Vertex end, EdgeLabel label) : from(start), to(end), edgeLabel(label) {};
        const Vertex & getFrom() const;
        const Vertex & getTo() const;
        const EdgeLabel& getLabel() const;
        void setLabel(const EdgeLabel& lab);
        ~Edge(){}
    };

    struct VertexPointerComparer {
        bool operator()(const typename std::list<Vertex>::iterator a, const typename std::list<Vertex>::iterator b) const {
            return a ->getId() < b -> getId();
        }
    };

    typedef typename std::list<Vertex>::iterator VertexIterator;

    class EdgeIterator {
    private:
        typename std::list<std::map<typename std::list<Vertex>::iterator, Edge, VertexPointerComparer>>::iterator base;
    public:
        EdgeIterator(typename std::list<std::map<typename std::list<Vertex>::iterator, Edge, VertexPointerComparer>> newBase) : base(newBase.begin()) {}
        bool operator==(const EdgeIterator & other) {
            return base == other.base;
        }
        bool operator!=(const EdgeIterator & other) {
            return base != other.base;
        }
        EdgeIterator & operator++() {
            base++;
            return EdgeIterator(++base);
        }
        EdgeIterator operator++(int) {
            return EdgeIterator(++base);
        }
        EdgeIterator & operator--() {
            base--;
            return *this;
        }
        EdgeIterator operator--(int) {
            return EdgeIterator(--base);
        }
        const Edge & operator*() const {
            const std::map<typename std::list<Vertex>::iterator, Edge, VertexPointerComparer>::iterator iter = base->begin();
            Graph<VertexLabel, EdgeLabel>::Edge next = iter->second;
            return next;
        }
        Edge* operator->() {
            std::map<typename std::list<Vertex>::iterator, Edge, VertexPointerComparer>::iterator iter = base->begin();
            Graph<VertexLabel, EdgeLabel>::Edge next = iter->second;
            return &next;
        }
        virtual ~EdgeIterator() {  }
        typedef std::bidirectional_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        typedef Edge value_type;
        typedef int difference_type;
        typedef Edge * pointer;
        typedef Edge & reference;
    };

    Vertex& addVertex(const VertexLabel& label);
    void addEdge(const Vertex& from, const Vertex & to, const EdgeLabel & label);
    VertexIterator verticesBegin();
    VertexIterator verticesEnd();
    EdgeIterator edgesBegin(const Vertex& v) const;
    EdgeIterator edgesEnd(const Vertex& v) const;
    std::list<std::map<typename std::list<Vertex>::iterator, Edge, 
    virtual ~Graph(){}

private:
    unsigned long id;
    std::list<Vertex> nodes;
    std::list<std::map<typename std::list<Vertex>::iterator, Edge, VertexPointerComparer>> neighbours;
};
```

I've been trying to implement method:

```
EdgeIterator edgesBegin(const Vertex& v) const;
```

It is supposed to iterate through all `Vertex`'s from `neighbours` and return iterator to `Vertex`'s that comes from that vertex. Here's what I have:

```
template<class VertexLabel, class EdgeLabel>
typename Graph<VertexLabel, EdgeLabel>::EdgeIterator Graph<VertexLabel, EdgeLabel>::edgesBegin(const Vertex & v) const
{
    std::list<std::map<typename std::list<Vertex>::iterator, Edge, VertexPointerComparer>> valid;
    std::list<std::map<typename std::list<Vertex>::iterator, Edge, VertexPointerComparer>>::const_iterator i;
    for (i = this->neighbours.begin(); i != this->neighbours.end(); i++) {
        std::map<typename std::list<Vertex>::iterator, Edge, VertexPointerComparer>::const_iterator mapIter = i-> begin();
        std::list<Vertex>::iterator vertex = mapIter->first;
        Edge edge = mapIter->second;
        if (vertex-> getId() == v.getId() && edge.getFrom().getId() == v.getId()) {
            valid.push_back(*i);
        }
    }
    return EdgeIterator(valid);
}
```

Unfortuntely, when I'm trying to to sth like that:

```
graph.addEdge(n1, n2, 10.0);
    graph.addEdge(n2, n3, 0.5);
    graph.addEdge(n3, n4, 2.2);
    graph.addEdge(n4, n1, 4.1);
    graph.addEdge(n4, n2, 3.0);
    EdgeIterator edgeIter = graph.edgesBegin(n2);
    std::cout << edgeIter->getFrom().getId();
```

I'm getting error that `EdgeIterator` cannot be dereferenced. I'm having troubles with debugging (I don't know why Visual Studio doesn't hit my breakpoints when I run in debug mode, I've searched through subjects on that, but nothing works for me) the reason.

I've been figthing with this quite a long time now, can anybody help me? My suspision is that `valid` object, that I'm returning passing to the `EdgeIterator` constructor is being destroyed after leaving the method `edgesBegin`, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT:**
Here's the `addEdge()` method needed to recover this situation:

```
template<class VertexLabel, class EdgeLabel>
void Graph<VertexLabel, EdgeLabel>::addEdge(const Vertex & from, const Vertex & to, const EdgeLabel & label)
{
    std::map<typename std::list<Vertex>::iterator, Edge, VertexPointerComparer> start;
    Edge* edgeA = new Edge(from, to, label);
    Edge* edgeB = new Edge(to, from, label);

    VertexIterator iterStart = this->verticesBegin();
    int advancer = (int)from.getId();
    std::advance(iterStart, advancer);
    start[iterStart] = *edgeA;

    this->neighbours.push_back(start);
}
```

Comment: I find it hard to see what the problem is without a [mcve].

Comment: What's `iters`, and how, if at all, is it related to `edgeIter`? I do not see `edgeIter` being dereferenced, or in fact used in any way, in the code you've shown.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry, I've copied it in a wrong way. It's updated now + I've added a method needed to replay the situation. Can you help me now or maybe there is anything I can add?

Comment: `EdgeIterator::operator->` returns a pointer to a local variable. That variable is destroyed, and the pointer becomes dangling, as soon as the function returns. Any attempt to use that pointer exhibits undefined behavior. Make it `Graph<VertexLabel, EdgeLabel>::Edge& next = iter->second;` (note the ampersand), see if that helps. Same problem with `operator*`

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me an example how it should be done correctly? How should I return that in a poper way? Can u just answer if it's easy for you :) I think there's also problem with `return EdgeIterator(valid);` cause the first line in `EdgeIterator::operator->` also gives the error that `list operator is not deferencable`. I'm confused..

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I've changed it the way you told and now I'm getting the error that `list is not deferencable".` It's in the first line of the `EdgeIterator::operator ->`.

Comment: You pas `newBase` to `EdgeIterator` constructor by value - in other words, you pass a temporary copy. Then you save an iterator to the first element of that temporary. Then the temporary is destroyed, leaving `base` dangling. You want to pass by reference, as in `std:list<...>& newBase`. Though that won't help either - you construct `EdgeIterator` from a local variable anyway. You need to make it so that the collection the iterator is iterating over actually lives at least as long as the iterator.

Comment: Your design ain't going to work. You can't do the filtering in `edgesBegin` - you'll have to do it in `EdgeIterator::operator++`. You need to have it iterate over `Grapth::neighbours` directly, skipping those that don't satisfy the condition.

Comment: This is a requirement to implement `edgesBegin` method. Now it still doesn't work, even if I pass by reference..